Creating a GUI/PSQL based postgre SQL table editor
I am planning to create a GUI and PSQL based postgre SQL table editor for my project. The front end is React and Backend is Node JS. Now in order to create the table, I can simple provide user with a SQL editor and run the raw query after sanitization. But in order to update a table, I will first need to fetch the current .sql of a table and then edit it. Is there any way to obtain the .sql file/ string without using pg_dump as I am avoiding to use pg_dump as a dependency to download.
